# Equations, arrows and comments on the go in Beamer

Tags: beamer, macros, tikz-arrows

I like the way tikZ combined with beamer can highlight equations (it works well with beamerarticle and article mode as well) as in [TeXexample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/)
I often use this feature but i think the code is difficult to manipulate "on the go".
I'd like to create a `newcommand` (?) `\EqNComments` (Equation and Comments) I could call easily in my code.

```
    \EqNComments
    {$\Delta$}{=}{Le point Delta}
    {$\mathcal{N}(d_1)$}{+}{Hedge ratio}
    {$K.e^{-rt}.\mathcal{N}(d_2)$}{}{Strike actualised}
```

[image]

Here is MWE that works very well with 3x3 elements.

1. I am stuck with the limitation of 9 in `newcommand` parameters
2. I have trouble inputing a `\foreach` to optimize my code
3. There must be a more intelligent way of processing this matter...

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   %\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
   %\usepackage[envcountsect]{beamerarticle}
   \usetheme{Warsaw}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

   \tikzset{
       Col1/.style= {fill=blue!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt},
       Col2/.style= {Col1, fill=red!20},
       Col3/.style= {Col1, fill=green!20},
   }

   \newcommand{\EqNComments}[9]
   {

   \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
   \tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]

   \begin{frame}
       \begin{equation}
                       \tikz[baseline] {\node[Col1] (d1) {#1};}  #2
                       \tikz[baseline] {\node[Col2] (d2) {#4};}  #5
                       \tikz[baseline] {\node[Col3] (d3) {#7};}  #8                    
   %                   \tikz[baseline] {\node[Col3] (d4) {#10};} #11                    
       \end{equation}

       \begin{itemize}
           \item #3 
           \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s1) {};
           \item #6 
           \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s2) {};        
           \item #9  
           \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s3) {};
   %       \item #12  
   %       \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s4) {};        
       \end{itemize}

       \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
           \path[->] (s1) edge [bend left]     (d1);
           \path[->] (s2) edge [bend right]    (d2);
           \path[->] (s3) edge [out=0, in=-90] (d3);
   %       \path[->] (s4) edge [out=0, in=-90] (d4);       
       \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{frame}
   } 

   \begin{document}

   \EqNComments
   {$\Delta$}{=}{Le point Delta}
   {$\mathcal{N}(d_1)$}{+}{Hedge ratio}
   {$K.e^{-rt}.\mathcal{N}(d_2)$}{-}{Strike actualised}
   %{dividendes}{.}{Not working here if I try to extend the command to 12 arguments}

   \end{document}
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does something of that sort. It uses the `tikzmark` library, which is a better tool because, among other things, it does not destroy the spacing and detects the mode we are in. Any quantity can be annotated with

```
\tmn{<quantity>}{<annotation>}
```

As long as you put those in an `AnnotatedEquation` environment, they will get annotated by the list similarly to what you are doing. The nodes will be using the styles `Col1`, `Col2` etc. to the extent they are defined. You can use the optional argument to add some keys.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcounter{mytn}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tmn}[3][]{\stepcounter{mytn}%
\tikzmarknode[Col\the\numexpr\value{mytn}-\mytn@start\relax/.try,inner xsep=2pt,%
minimum height=1.6em,#1]{mytn-\number\value{mytn}}{#2}%
\expandafter\gdef\csname tmn@annot@\number\value{mytn}\endcsname{#3}}
\newenvironment{AnnotatedEquation}{\edef\mytn@start{\number\value{mytn}}%
\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}%
\edef\mytn@end{\number\value{mytn}}%
\ifnum\mytn@end>\mytn@start
\begin{itemize}
 \foreach \X in {\the\numexpr\mytn@start+1,...,\mytn@end} 
 {\item \tikzmarknode{mytn-annot-\X}{\csname tmn@annot@\X\endcsname}%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw[-stealth] (mytn-annot-\X.east) to[out=0,in=-90] (mytn-\X.south);
 \end{tikzpicture}} 
\end{itemize}
\fi}
\makeatother
\tikzset{ Col1/.style= {fill=blue!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt}, 
Col2/.style= {Col1, fill=red!20}, 
Col3/.style= {Col1, fill=green!20}, }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Some annotated equation}
\begin{AnnotatedEquation}
 \tmn{\Delta}{Le point Delta}= \tmn{\mathcal{N}(d_1)}{Hedge ratio}-
 \tmn{K\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-r\,t}\cdot\mathcal{N}(d_2)}{Strike actualised} 
\end{AnnotatedEquation}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Another annotated equation}
\begin{AnnotatedEquation}
 \tmn{\Delta}{Le point Delta}= \tmn{\mathcal{N}(d_1)}{Hedge ratio}-
 \tmn{K\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-r\,t}\cdot\mathcal{N}(d_2)}{Strike actualised} 
 +\tmn{\xi}{a Weyl spinor}
 +\tmn{\eta}{another Weyl spinor}
\end{AnnotatedEquation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a version that works with `external`.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,external}
\newcounter{mytn}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tmn}[3][]{\stepcounter{mytn}%
\tikzmarknode[Col\the\numexpr\value{mytn}-\mytn@start\relax/.try,inner xsep=2pt,%
minimum height=1.6em,#1]{mytn-\number\value{mytn}}{#2}%
\expandafter\gdef\csname tmn@annot@\number\value{mytn}\endcsname{#3}}
\newenvironment{AnnotatedEquation}{\edef\mytn@start{\number\value{mytn}}%
\tikzexternaldisable
\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}%
\edef\mytn@end{\number\value{mytn}}%
\ifnum\mytn@end>\mytn@start
\begin{itemize}
 \foreach \X in {\the\numexpr\mytn@start+1,...,\mytn@end} 
 {\item \tikzmarknode{mytn-annot-\X}{\csname tmn@annot@\X\endcsname}%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw[-stealth] (mytn-annot-\X.east) to[out=0,in=-90] (mytn-\X.south);
 \end{tikzpicture}} 
\end{itemize}
\fi\tikzexternalenable}
\makeatother
\tikzset{ Col1/.style= {fill=blue!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt}, 
Col2/.style= {Col1, fill=red!20}, 
Col3/.style= {Col1, fill=green!20}, }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Some annotated equation}
\begin{AnnotatedEquation}
 \tmn{\Delta}{Le point Delta}= \tmn{\mathcal{N}(d_1)}{Hedge ratio}-
 \tmn{K\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-r\,t}\cdot\mathcal{N}(d_2)}{Strike actualised} 
\end{AnnotatedEquation}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Another annotated equation}
\begin{AnnotatedEquation}
 \tmn{\Delta}{Le point Delta}= \tmn{\mathcal{N}(d_1)}{Hedge ratio}-
 \tmn{K\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-r\,t}\cdot\mathcal{N}(d_2)}{Strike actualised} 
 +\tmn{\xi}{a Weyl spinor}
 +\tmn{\eta}{another Weyl spinor}
\end{AnnotatedEquation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM**: Here is a more complicated but also more general version that allows one to tune the arrows. This can be done by using the `special arrow` key. For instance,

```
\tmn[special arrow={out=90,annotations/out anchor=north}]{\Delta}{Le point Delta}= \tmn{\mathcal{N}(d_1)}{Hedge ratio}
```

instructs the arrow to come out from the north of the annotation text, and leave at an angle of 90 degrees. The defaults are the east anchor and 0 degrees. This is particularly helpful when dealing with numerators of fractions.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,external}
\newcounter{mytn}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tmn}[3][]{\stepcounter{mytn}%
\tikzmarknode[annotations/Col\the\numexpr\value{mytn}-\mytn@start\relax/.try,inner xsep=2pt,%
minimum height=1.6em,#1]{mytn-\number\value{mytn}}{#2}%
\expandafter\gdef\csname tmn@annot@\number\value{mytn}\endcsname{#3}}
\tikzset{special arrow/.code={%
\expandafter\xdef\csname tmn@arrow@style@\number\value{mytn}\endcsname{#1}}}
\newenvironment{AnnotatedEquation}{\edef\mytn@start{\number\value{mytn}}%
\tikzexternaldisable
\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}%
\edef\mytn@end{\number\value{mytn}}%
\ifnum\mytn@end>\mytn@start
\begin{itemize}
 \foreach \X in {\the\numexpr\mytn@start+1,...,\mytn@end} 
 {\item \tikzmarknode{mytn-annot-\X}{\csname tmn@annot@\X\endcsname}%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \ifcsname tmn@arrow@style@\X\noexpand\endcsname
   \draw[-stealth,out=0,in=-90,
    style/.expanded=\csname tmn@arrow@style@\X\noexpand\endcsname] 
    (mytn-annot-\X.\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/annotations/out anchor}) 
    to (mytn-\X.\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/annotations/in anchor});
  \else
   \draw[-stealth,out=0,in=-90] (mytn-annot-\X.\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/annotations/out anchor})
    to (mytn-\X.\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/annotations/in anchor});
  \fi
 \end{tikzpicture}} 
\end{itemize}
\fi\tikzexternalenable}
\makeatother
\tikzset{annotations/.cd, 
Col1/.style= {fill=blue!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt}, 
Col2/.style= {annotations/Col1, fill=red!20}, 
Col3/.style= {annotations/Col1, fill=green!20}, 
in anchor/.initial=south,out anchor/.initial=east}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Some annotated equation}
\begin{AnnotatedEquation}
 \tmn{\Delta}{Le point Delta}= \tmn{\mathcal{N}(d_1)}{Hedge ratio}-
 \tmn{K\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-r\,t}\cdot\mathcal{N}(d_2)}{Strike actualised} 
\end{AnnotatedEquation}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Another annotated equation}
\begin{AnnotatedEquation}
 \tmn[special arrow={out=90,annotations/out anchor=north}]{\Delta}{Le point Delta}= \tmn{\mathcal{N}(d_1)}{Hedge ratio}-
 \tmn{K\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-r\,t}\cdot\mathcal{N}(d_2)}{Strike actualised} 
 +\frac{\tmn[special arrow={in=-160,annotations/in anchor=west}]{\xi}{a Weyl spinor}}{\tmn{\eta}{another Weyl spinor}}
\end{AnnotatedEquation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Further improvements are possible, but require input from users who actually use this.

Comment: You're no cat, you're a lion :) Merci, that is exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: Just a last question, is it possible that the code generates an error when using tikzexternal  ? ("giving up on this path")

Comment: Yes, quite possible. I am now in a long line to get food, will look at it later, but most likely one has to switch off externalize for the environment (locally).

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb I added a version that should work with external.

Comment: My very last question, how shall i consider another approach (another question) to cope with \frak{A}{B} when I want to give a comment on A and B ?

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb Assuming you mean `\frac` with a `c`, you can use `\frac{\tmn{\xi}{a Weyl spinor}+1}{\tmn{\eta}{another Weyl spinor}}`. The only problem is when both nodes are on top of each other, then the arrow will run through.

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb I wasn't happy with the solution so I added a more general (but perhaps also more complicated) version. The basic usage is the same. It is at the end of the post.

Comment: It works like a charm ! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106071/discussion-between-julien-elie-taieb-and-schrodingers-cat).