# Keeping the Track of the AnnotatedEquation color

Tags: color, tikz-styles, annotations

I'm following this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/535624/equations-arrows-and-comments-on-the-go-in-beamer) to give annotation in my equation. What my plan is to keep the track of the color of certain equation segment, so it can be understood easily.

If you see the two equation, their color did not match. What would be the best way to keep track of the color of the fragmented equation, so they can be identified easily?
[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcounter{mytn}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tmn}[3][]{\stepcounter{mytn}%
\tikzmarknode[Col\the\numexpr\value{mytn}-\mytn@start\relax/.try,inner xsep=2pt,%
minimum height=1.6em,#1]{mytn-\number\value{mytn}}{#2}%
\expandafter\gdef\csname tmn@annot@\number\value{mytn}\endcsname{#3}}
\newenvironment{AnnotatedEquation}{\edef\mytn@start{\number\value{mytn}}%
\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}%
\edef\mytn@end{\number\value{mytn}}%
\ifnum\mytn@end>\mytn@start
\begin{itemize}
 \foreach \X in {\the\numexpr\mytn@start+1,...,\mytn@end} 
 {\item \tikzmarknode{mytn-annot-\X}{\csname tmn@annot@\X\endcsname}%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw[-stealth] (mytn-annot-\X.east) to[out=0,in=-90] (mytn-\X.south);
 \end{tikzpicture}} 
\end{itemize}
\fi}
\makeatother
\tikzset{ Col1/.style= {fill=blue!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt}, 
Col2/.style= {Col1, fill=red!20}, 
Col3/.style= {Col1, fill=green!20}, }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Some annotated equation}
\begin{AnnotatedEquation}
 \tmn{\Delta}{Le point Delta}= \tmn{\mathcal{N}(d_1)}{Hedge ratio}-
 \tmn{K\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-r\,t}\cdot\mathcal{N}(d_2)}{Strike actualised} 
\end{AnnotatedEquation}

\begin{AnnotatedEquation}
 \tmn{K\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-r\,t}\cdot\mathcal{N}(d_2)}{Strike actualised} =
  \tmn{S\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-r\,t}\cdot\mathcal{N}(d_2)}{Strike actualised} 
  + \tmn{\mathcal{N}(d_1)}{Hedge ratio}-
 \tmn{K\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-r\,t}\cdot\mathcal{N}(d_2)}{Strike actualised} 
\end{AnnotatedEquation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

UPDATE:

Sorry from the next same color definition, I won't need the annotated text anymore. How not to give the text command? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quite simple solution would be to redefine your colours between both your equations.

[image: redefining coulours]

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcounter{mytn}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tmn}[3][]{\stepcounter{mytn}%
\tikzmarknode[Col\the\numexpr\value{mytn}-\mytn@start\relax/.try,inner xsep=2pt,%
minimum height=1.6em,#1]{mytn-\number\value{mytn}}{#2}%
\expandafter\gdef\csname tmn@annot@\number\value{mytn}\endcsname{#3}}
\newenvironment{AnnotatedEquation}{\edef\mytn@start{\number\value{mytn}}%
\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}%
\edef\mytn@end{\number\value{mytn}}%
\ifnum\mytn@end>\mytn@start
\begin{itemize}
 \foreach \X in {\the\numexpr\mytn@start+1,...,\mytn@end} 
 {\item \tikzmarknode{mytn-annot-\X}{\csname tmn@annot@\X\endcsname}%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw[-stealth] (mytn-annot-\X.east) to[out=0,in=-90] (mytn-\X.south);
 \end{tikzpicture}} 
\end{itemize}
\fi}
\makeatother
\tikzset{ Col1/.style= {fill=blue!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt}, 
Col2/.style= {Col1, fill=red!20}, 
Col3/.style= {Col1, fill=green!20}, }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Some annotated equation}
\begin{AnnotatedEquation}
 \tmn{\Delta}{Le point Delta}= \tmn{\mathcal{N}(d_1)}{Hedge ratio}-
 \tmn{K\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-r\,t}\cdot\mathcal{N}(d_2)}{Strike actualised} 
\end{AnnotatedEquation}

\tikzset{ Col2/.style= {fill=blue!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt}, 
Col3/.style= {Col2, fill=red!20}, 
Col1/.style= {Col2, fill=green!20}, }
\begin{AnnotatedEquation}
 \tmn{K\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-r\,t}\cdot\mathcal{N}(d_2)}{Strike actualised} =
  \tmn{S\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-r\,t}\cdot\mathcal{N}(d_2)}{Strike actualised} 
  + \tmn{\mathcal{N}(d_1)}{Hedge ratio}-
 \tmn{K\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-r\,t}\cdot\mathcal{N}(d_2)}{Strike actualised} 
\end{AnnotatedEquation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is their any way we put the color from the color definition, but not adding the annotated text?